# Finding the length of a List paired with the first input element

Tags: prolog

I need to implement a predicate that can

```
size_sub([[a,a,a],[b,b]],X).
and returns 
[a,3],[b,2]
```

so far what i have achieved

```
size_sub(A,Ls):-
maplist(length,A,Ls).
returns 
[3,2]
```

How can i modify the existing functionality to return a value number pair.

Comment: You need to pass a different predicate to `maplist` other than `length`. Write a predicate like, `reduce([a,a,a], [a,3]) :- ...` That yields `[a,3]` when given `[a,a,a]`. If it's already assuming all the elements are the same, then this should be easy. Then call `maplist(reduce, A, Ls).`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass to maplist a predicate doing what is appropriate, like

```
size_sub(A,Ls):-
    maplist(list_sym_len,A,Ls).
list_sym_len([Sym|Rest], [Sym, Len]) :- length([Sym|Rest], Len).
```

or use library lambda. In SWI-Prolog you can get it with

```
?- pack_install(lambda).
```

when installed, you can sometime shorthand your definition

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).
?- maplist(\[Sym|Rest]^[Sym,Len]^length([Sym|Rest], Len), [[a,a,a],[b,c]],R).
R = [[a, 3], [b, 2]].
```